# In-ear earphone to sleep

Tags: sleep, earplugs-earphones, noise-induce-hearing-harm

I live in an apartment where sometimes neighbors make noise at bedtime.
I have trouble sleeping, any noise, if it isn't a constant noise, bothers me.
So, I started listening to music before bed and it significantly improved the quality of my sleep. And I use a headset similar to [that](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B01BY7ZMXC) (not exactly this, I think mine is more comfortable, but just to have an idea of the size): it seems too big to use during sleep, and that's right, but despite that he is Well comfortable and less troublesome than the intra earphones I have. So, I listen to music with it until I fall asleep. After a while, I wake up, and shoot him, but since I'm already sleepy, I can go back to sleep quickly.
But I wanted something I could use all night.

I know of the existence of [these](http://www.sleepphones.com/) sleep phones, but I don't know if they are perfectly adequate. At first glance, the sound seems a little weak. I usually listen to heavy rock and it's important that the sound quality is good.

So I wanted to buy an in-ear earphone. But I wanted it to be very comfortable to use all night and the sound quality is reasonable. Does anyone have something in this sense to indicate?

Comment: I'm trying to find a medical question here but all I'm finding is a request for opinions and product recommendations, which makes it off topic. Can you please edit your question and make it a specific question that can be answered with facts rather than opinions?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it isn't a health question.

Comment: sleep well is healthy, no more

Comment: @alexpfx The internet is full of sites offering advice, reviews, and opinions that would welcome your question. This just doesn't happen to be one of them. You might want to have a read of the help center and learn what stackexchange is about before asking questions in any of the areas.

Comment: It is a matter of interpretation and common sense. you can see a question about benefits/harms of listening to music during sleeping or a question about headphone quality

Answer (score 3):

Asking for earphones/headphones which have **a good sound quality** is not on-topic for this group as this generates opinion related answers at best.  Some people's idea of good quality can be very different to others.  To highlight this I wonder where you get the idea that sound quality is poor when there are no sound specifications provided on the website.

If you are after something which can be safely used whilst asleep to take noise away, then as far as earphones/headphones is concerned, it **seems** that the SleepPhones you linked to would be more comfortable based on the testimonials.  As a personal opinion, if you go for them it **may** be best to go for the wireless ones to prevent strangulation by the cord on corded phones.

Aside from this, there are earplugs which you can buy to remove sound.  However if having music helps you sleep then this will not be the answer for you.  To select the right earplugs for you, you may want to look at [Cooper Safety's Webpage](http://www.coopersafety.com/earplugs-noise-reduction) and read up on the information on NRR values. Specifically, the section on **How does NRR change decibels of exposure?**  They also list on the page, typical sound levels in decibels (dB) of various sounds in order for you to estimate the dB levels you want to cancel out.

I wish you luck in your search for something which is right for you.